# Unity does not show me the problematic files when it shows me the build error "Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors"

Tags: unity, build

I am trying to build an APK in Unity 2019.4.39. Unity says that the build failed, but it does not tell me the files that caused the failed build.

**Can anyone please tell me how to figure out which files caused the build to fail ?**

---

Here are the build errors:

```
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002b3] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:964] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform)
```

---

Here is an image of the error message on the console:

[image]

---

PS: I know that there is an excellent answer to fix the build error "**Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors**" at this link on StackOverFlow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588709/error-when-building-project-error-building-player-because-scripts-have-compile/42588940#42588940

However, in my case, Unity does even says which files are bad. So, I can't fix the error if I don't know which files cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my own issue.  Basically,  the problem is that my project contains 2 versions of **DOTween**, and 2 versions of **Lean**. This causes the build errors.

But, if I only build the scene (without "Play" the scene first), then Unity won't tell me the files or packages that cause the build errors.

I have to "Play" the scene in Unity, and then it will tell me the files or packages that cause that are duplicated, and cause the build error.

---

Here are the details:

To find out what files or packages cause the build errors, I need to "Play" the scene in Unity. When the scene is played in Unity, it tells me that there are 2 conflicting versions of 2 different packages: **DOTween** and **Lean**.

The reason is that my old project already has 1 version of **DOTween** and **Lean**. When I install a new unity package (called **Game_Menu**), it also installs a new version of DOTween and a new version of Lean without deleting or overwriting the old versions. So, there are 2 versions of DOTween, and 2 versions of Lean in my project. This causes the build error.

My solution is to manually remove 1 version of DOTween and 1 version of Lean. Then, Unity builds the APK successfully.

---

In the future, whenever I install this Unity package (called **Game_Menu**), I will need to check to see if my project already contains **DOTween** or **Lean**. If it already does, then I don't need to install these 2 packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I would guess that the compiler error is caused by code that's nested between platform-specific compiler flags. Since you're building an Android APK, the first places I would look would be anywhere in your solution containing code within the compiler flags `#if UNITY_ANDROID` or `#if ENABLE_IL2CPP`.